# CSV Python list

Tags: python, list, csv, minimum

```
Name  Gender Physics Maths
A                 45     55
X                 22     64
C                 0       86
```

I have a csv file like this, I have made some modification to get list with only the marks in the form [[45,55],[22,64]]

I want to find the minimum for each subject.
But when I run my code, I only get the minimum for the first subject and the other values are copied from the row 
The answer I want - [0,55]
The answer I get - [0,86]

```
def find_min(marks,cols,rows):
minimum = []
temp = []

for list in marks:
    min1 = min([x for x in list])
    minimum.append(min1)


  # for j in range(rows):
#    for i in range(cols):
 #       temp.append(marks)
  #      x = min(temp)


   #     minimum.append(x)
return minimum
```

How do I modify my code
I cant use any other modules/libraries like csv or pandas
i tries using zip(*marks) - But that just prints my marks list as is.
Is there any way to separate the inner-lists from the larger lists

Answer (score 1):

Try transposing the `marks` array (which is one student per row) so each list entry corresponds to a column ("subject") from your CSV:

```
def find_min(marks):
    mt = zip(*marks)
    mins = [min(row) for row in mt]
    return mins
```

example usage:

```
marks = [[45,55],[22,64],[0,86]]
print(find_min(marks))
```

which prints:

```
[0, 55]
```

Comment: added "example usage" above.  `find_min(marks)` returns a list of minimums.

Answer (score 1):

This will calculate the **minimum per subject**:

```
In [707]: marks = [[45,55],[22,64]]

In [697]: [min(idx) for idx in zip(*marks)]                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[697]: [22, 55]
```